# SharePoint 2010 column dependency when editing another column of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listitem

Is there a way to require that a column must be updated if a certain column is updated in a list item?  Something that could be done during the configuration of the list through a browser edit or SP designer.

so if i have a list with say columns A, B, C
the list item has been created with only A filled in.
Someone edits the list item by filling in B
i need to require that C contains data if B has data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a PreSaveAction javascript function.

For more information, see [how do I validate form fields in sharepoint list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337144/how-do-i-validate-form-fields-in-sharepoint-list).