# Validation of multivalued columns in sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a list in Sharepoint 2010 which has a "Choice" type column that can take multiple values through checkboxes. I'm using the default "NewForm" provided to input a new item into the list. I need to perform some validation before a new item gets added depending upon which all checkbox items have been selected. How close can I get to an out-of-the box validation approach as Sharepoint does not allow validations on multivalued Choices by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PreSaveAction. This functionality is provided out of the box to allow for custom client side validation.

For more information on PreSaveAction, see [how do I validate form fields in sharepoint list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337144/how-do-i-validate-form-fields-in-sharepoint-list)